# Using ISNULL function with LEAD function: having trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm having trouble combining the LEAD and ISNULL function. The basic query is like this:

```
DECLARE @ReportTimeStart DATETIME = '2019-04-25 06:50'
DECLARE @ReportTimeEnd DATETIME = '2019-04-25 23:59';

SELECT
    [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
    [Machine_State],
    [t_stamp],
    LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) NextStateTime
FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN @ReportTimeStart AND @ReportTimeEnd
```

This gives me a long list like this:

```
tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx    Machine_State    t_stamp                    NextStateTime
5893                       130              2019-04-25 23:44:49.160    2019-04-25 23:46:34.670
5894                       170              2019-04-25 23:46:34.670    2019-04-25 23:50:01.370
5895                       100              2019-04-25 23:50:01.370    NULL
```

I want to use the ISNULL() function to replace that last NULL value with the end time of my report. Like this:

```
SELECT
    [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
    [Machine_State],
    [t_stamp],
    ISNULL(
    (LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) NextStateTime),
    @ReportTimeEnd)
  FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
  WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN @ReportTimeStart AND @ReportTimeEnd
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `unfortunately this doesn't work.` How does it not working ? Your query won't execute due to syntax error ? You are not getting the result you want ? And what is the expected result ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `default` argument? `LEAD([t_stamp], 1, @ReportTimeEnd) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx])`

Answer (score 2):

[`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function accepts a "default" value that is returned when it crosses the end of the window. Use it like so:

```
SELECT
    [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
    [Machine_State],
    [t_stamp],
    LEAD([t_stamp], 1, @ReportTimeEnd) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) AS NextStateTime
    -- ----------------^
FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN @ReportTimeStart AND @ReportTimeEnd
```

This approach is useful if you want to distinguish between the last value and a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
    [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
    [Machine_State],
    [t_stamp],
    ISNULL(LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]),@ReportTimeEnd) NextStateTime
  FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
  WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN @ReportTimeStart AND @ReportTimeEnd
```

I think you have a sintax error here:

```
ISNULL(
    (LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) NextStateTime),
    @ReportTimeEnd)
```